# Jira Soap API get project version start/end date

Tags: api, soap, jira

I am trying to the get start and end date of a jira project version.
Can I do this with the Jira SOAP API, and how cand I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by JIRA project version? Do you mean the start and end date of a regular project, such as a sed task or a slpm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as 'start date' for version in JIRA, and Release Date is available via SOAP. E.g. in Java:

```
JiraSoapService js = new JiraSoapServiceServiceLocator().getJirasoapserviceV2();
String token = js.login(username, password);
RemoteVersion[] versions = js.getVersions(token, "KEY");
Calendar releaseDate = versions[0].getReleaseDate();
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity:

I'm guessing you are using Greenhopper, that does allow you to specify start and end dates for your sprints/versions. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear you can not retrieve this data via the API as Greenhopper data is not exposed (yet). See the ticket below.

I'm anxious to get this too.

http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-1853

Answer (score 0):

```
https://[YOUR_JIRA_HOST]/secure/CCBShowChartReport.jspa
?decorator=none
&selectedProjectId=[PROJECT_ID]
&selectedBoardId=[VERSION_ID]
&chartType=gh.chart.ahourburndown
&fieldId=
&forMaster=false
```

Not really for startDate / endDate, but all information needed to build your own Hourly-Burndown Chart...

I searched for hours to find a solution for a this, the only other way I found was this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `propertytext`
WHERE ID = (
SELECT ID
FROM `propertyentry`
WHERE ENTITY_NAME = 'GREENHOPPER'
AND ENTITY_ID = YOUR_PROJECT_ID
AND PROPERTY_KEY = 'CONFIGURATION' )
```

With this you get a XML File for your Version and in this you can find the values for startDate / endDate